# Python: Remove character only from end of string if character is ="/"

Tags: python

I add different Values to the Houdini Variables with Python.

Some of these Variables are file pathes and end with an `"/"` - others are just names and do not end with an `"/"`.

In my current code I use `[:-1]` to remove the last character of the filepath, so I dont have the `"/"`.
The problem is, that if I add a Value like `"Var_ABC"`, the result will be `"Var_AB"` since it also removes the last character.

How can i remove the last character only if the last character is a `"/"`?

Thats what I have and it works so far:

```
def set_vars():   

count = hou.evalParm('vars_names')
user_name = hou.evalParm('user_name')

for idx in range( 1,count+1):
    output = hou.evalParm('vars_' + str(idx))
    vars_path_out = hou.evalParm('vars_path_' + str(idx))
    vars_path = vars_path_out[:-1]

    hou.hscript("setenv -g " + output + "=" + vars_path)

    final_vars = hou.hscript("setenv -g " + output + "=" + vars_path)

    hou.ui.displayMessage(user_name +", " + "all variables are set.")
```

Thank you

Comment: you should add an `if` to check whether the last character is `\` or not

Comment: This is exactly what the `.rstrip()` method of strings is good for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonharper mentioned in the comments, you should probably use [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) here. It is built-in and IMO more readable than the contitional one-liner:

```py
vars_path_out.rstrip('/')
```

This will strip out those strings which end with `/` and return without that ending. Otherwise it will return your string as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `endswith` method to check if it ends with /

```
if vars_path_out.endswith('/')
```

Or simply check the last character:

```
if vars_path_out[-1] == '/'
```

Like this:

```
vars_path = vars_path_out[:-1] if vars_path_out.endswith('/') else vars_path_out
```

Or like this:

```
if vars_path_out.endswith('\'):
  vars_path = vars_path_out[:-1]
else:
  vars_path = vars_path_out
```

another way is `rstrip` method:

```
vars_path = vars_path_out.rstrip('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
vars_path_out = hou.evalParm('vars_path_' + str(idx))
if vars_path_out[-1] == '/':
 vars_path = vars_path_out[:-1]
```

**or**

based on the comment of [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper)

```
vars_path = vars_path_out.rstrip('/')
```

This is much better than the first